# How to add the results of a group, to the grouped documents? MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am creating some reports by passing this data:
`Reports Model`

```
userId : String,
marketId : String,
marketName : String,
itemId : String,
minPricePerKg : Number,
maxPricePerKg : Number
```

creating 3 reports by `POST` request :

```
POST /reports 

request 1:
{
  "details": {
    "userId": "1",
    "marketId": "1",
    "marketName": "market1",
    "itemId": "1",
    "minPricePerKg": "10",
    "maxPricePerKg": "20",
  }
}

request 2:
{
  "details": {
    "userId": "2",
    "marketId": "1",
    "marketName": "market1",
    "itemId": "1",
    "minPricePerKg": "20",
    "maxPricePerKg": "40",
  }
}

request 3:
{
  "details": {
    "userId": "1",
    "marketId": "2",
    "marketName": "market2",
    "itemId": "1",
    "minPricePerKg": "80",
    "maxPricePerKg": "100",
  }
}
```

---

I want to get the average price of all reports of some particular `itemId` (which is received from query).
So, for understanding we are filtering out all reports with `itemId`.. with `$match : { itemId }`

On Requesting
`GET /reports?itemId=1`

`Expected Output`

```
[
  {
    "marketId": "1",
    "itemId": "1",
    "marketName": "market1",
    "users": ["1", "2"],
    "minPrice": 15,
    "maxPrice": 30
  },
  {
    "marketId": "2",
    "itemId": "1",
    "marketName": "market2",
    "users": ["1"],
    "minPrice": 80,
    "maxPrice": 100
  }
]
```

here `minPrice` is average of all `minPricePerKg` and `maxPrice` is average of all `maxPricePerKg` of there respective `marketId's` report.
I want to get all the fields i.e(`marketId, marketName, users, itemId`) in result as well

---

output I am getting is:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "marketId": "market1"
    },
    "minPrice": 15,
    "maxPrice": 30
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "marketId": "market2"
    },
    "minPrice": 80,
    "maxPrice": 100
  }
]
```

---

my approach is something like this:

```
const res = await Report.aggregate([
  { $match: { itemId } },
  { $group: { _id: { marketId : "$marketId" }, minPrice: { $avg: '$minPricePerKg' }, maxPrice: { $avg: '$maxPricePerKg' } } },
  { $project: { "marketName": 1 } },
]);
```

Comment: can you add sample data in JSON and expected output in JSON? so we know what data you have, and what result you need.

Comment: edited the question.. please have a look again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- group to keep those field that are common in the group
- and accumulate those are not common `users` and `MinPrice` `MaxPrice`

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70365581-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$details"}},
  {"$group":  
    {"_id": 
      {"marketId": "$marketId",
        "itemId": "$itemId",
        "marketName": "$marketName"},
      "avgMinPrice": {"$avg": {"$toDouble": "$minPricePerKg"}},
      "avgMaxPrice": {"$avg": {"$toDouble": "$maxPricePerKg"}},
      "users": {"$push": "$userId"}}},
  {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": {"$mergeObjects": ["$_id", "$$ROOT"]}}},
  {"$project": {"_id": 0}}])
```

Comment: Actually No. What I want is first take all the collection with some `itemId`... Now, we are left with all the reports we want and who has its `minPricePerKg` and `maxPricePerKg`... Now from those, group all them as per there `marketId` and take the avg of there `minPricePerKg` and `maxPricePerKg`... and label as `minPrice` and `maxPrice`
So, basically it becomes there are unique `marketId` number of objects in response...
And which users made report on that `marketId` are also added...

Comment: ok update helped, i think this time it is what you need. (query assumes that the report data are in the database)

Comment: Yeah. It worked just had to remove `{"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$details"}}` initially as `details` are not present at start... And thanks. Learned new stuffs like `$replaceRoot` and `newRoot`...